# Sliding an image when the scroll reaches it

Tags: android, jquery, html

HTML:

```
<div id="slideimage">

<a href="#"> <img src="file:///android_asset/images/mainpageimage1.jpg"  style="width:100%; height:auto; padding-bottom:7px;" ></a>
<a href="#"> <img src="file:///android_asset/images/mainpageimage2.jpg" style="width:100%; height:auto;" ></a>

</div>
```

Script:

```
window.onscroll = function () { scrollFunction() };

function scrollFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 700 ) {
        $("slideimage").animate({left: '250px'});
    }
```

I have the code above but it doesn't do anything.

I just need a simple code to slide the image.

The problem is that the code is an Android app based on HTML code, not a website, and I'm new to it so I don't know if it works the same.

Answer (score 2):

You are forgetting the hash (#) in the jQuery selector.

```js
window.onscroll = function () { scrollFunction() };

function scrollFunction() {

  if (document.body.scrollTop > 700 ) {

    $('#slideimage').animate({left: '250px'});

  }

}
```

Check to see if it works right now.

Comment: it still didnt do any thing

Comment: Are you loading jQuery in your app? What is the framework you are using to create it?

Comment: yes i am loading jquery. the problem is that other jquery codes are working but  the animations are not